# Individually replace NaN in pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a 900 x 7 dataframe in which 3 fields contain some NaN values.

Instead of simply replacing these values with the some feature average, I have created a function to use an algorithm to estimate the likely value of each NaN based on the other values in that row.

How can I iterate over each NaN to change it's value using my custom function?

My function takes the row ID, the other feature names, and the feature containing the NaN as arguments.

E.g.

```
custom_fillnan(id=0, ins=["val0", "val1", "val2"], out="valn")
```

Example dataframe:

```
ID    val0    val1    val2    ...    valn
0      1        2       3     ...    NaN
1      1      NaN       3     ...     4
2      0        0     NaN     ...     1
...
```

Comment: Are you going to iterate with columns, rows or with each cell separately?

Comment: It would be preferable to iterate over rows

Comment: Does your algorithm give the same values per cell in each row? Or you need to extract indices?

Comment: The algorithm looks at the row the NaN occurs in and uses the other non-NaN values to estimate a replacement value for the NaN

Comment: ...it uses a subset of the non-NaN values in fact

Comment: Why you couldn't use `apply` with `axis=1` then?

Comment: I'll give that a try, but by the look of it that's the answer. Do you want to make an answer post for that with maybe a bit more detail for others

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you could use `apply` with `axis=1` and `fillna` with your custom function:

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
   ID  val0  val1  val2  valn
0   0     1     2     3   NaN
1   1     1   NaN     3     4
2   2     0     0   NaN     1


In [83]: df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(pd.np.mean(x.iloc[1:])), axis=1)
Out[83]: 
   ID  val0      val1      val2  valn
0   0     1  2.000000  3.000000     2
1   1     1  2.666667  3.000000     4
2   2     0  0.000000  0.333333     1
```

Instead of `pd.np.mean` you could use your function. `x.iloc[1:]` is used because, as I understand, you want to use for your function only `val` columns.

**EDIT**

If you want to get column names for missing values you could apply or use that function for processing:

```
def func(x):
    x.loc[x.isnull()] = x.index[x.isnull()]
    return x

In [209]: df.apply(func, axis=1)
Out[209]: 
   ID  val0  val1  val2  valn
0   0     1     2     3  valn
1   1     1  val1     3     4
2   2     0     0  val2     1
```

Comment: How can I determine which column the NaN occurred in? As this will affect which subset of columns is used to predict its value